# Dlookup returning "error" I am unsure what is wrong with the formula

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to put a formula in a form to return the "Account Balance" value from the "credit limit" query based off the "Customer or Vendor" selection in the form, which are listed as the "business partner" in the query .

```
DLookUp("[Credit Limit]![Account Balance]","[Credit Limit]","[Credit Limit]![Business Partner] = " & [Customer or Vendor])
```

Here is my Query, the name selected in the form matches "business partner", I want to rerun the "account balance" value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around text values:

```
=DLookUp("[Account Balance]","[Credit Limit]","[Business Partner] = '" & [Customer or Vendor] & "'")
```